# how fix JSX element 'html' has no corresponding closing tag in Visual Studio Code for test files

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to code unit tests to my vanilla web-components and all tests I write have a lot of warning as pasted in my question. I found some similar issues to others using ReactJs but it is not my case at all and, on top of that, my index.htnl file consuming the webcomponent doesn't show such warning: I only see it in test files. Well, I could ignore it but I would prefer figure out what configuration I am missing and realy on warnings as really important thing to check out. Maybe some extension I should add. I tried "Prettier - Code Formatter" without success.

The complete project can be clone from https://github.com/jimisdrpc/simplest-webcomponet

VSC picture

[image]

Comment: Why do you have HTML in a .js file if you're not using JSX?

Comment: Because this is a common way to create tests and run them via wct. Why did you get surprised I am using HTML in a .js file. Honestly I have read some unit test blogs driving me to use such approach for unit testing my vanilla web components throw wct. How would you unit test vanilla web components.